# Fullcalendar selectable is not working as i expected

Tags: fullcalendar

I have some issue here with fullcalendar `selectable` and i am not denying that it could be also my coding problem. Either both of them, i'm having an issue where i need to click and hold in order to create new event and even drag instead just click and create and click to drag. No. I need to hold and wait for a seconds, and then i can select it afterwards.

Is it something wrong with my code or this issue has been centered long before? I can't find on google about fullcalendar selectable problem though. I use Ionic with localstorage and chrome.

If i am using eventClick/dayClick, it is fine. There's no need for me to click and hold the button. However when i am using `selectable: 'true'` and also `selectHelper: 'true'` the problem that i just mentioned has occured.

NOTE: When implementing my coding on JSfiddle, it is working fine but when i see my calendar on chrome localhost, it's making that annoying problem. In addition to that, when i'm build into .apk, and i use it on my phone, the problem still occured.

Anyone got solution?

Comment: Show some code or put atleast jsfiddle link

Comment: My bad. This is the code that i have mostly.I have include the script src because i fear it is also can be consider as a main problem. http://jsfiddle.net/59RCB/204/

Answer (score 0):

touch devices are different than browsers, fullcalendar have a [documentation](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_ui/Touch_Support/) for supporting touch devices.

you can set the delay for selecting a cell using [longPressDelay](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_ui/longPressDelay/)

hope it helps.